# Moving clip with green screen

Tags: premiere, greenscreen, tracking

I'm working on a project that is using an old "film roll" as a base for it: [image: image here] I want to have different clips for each color, and I plan on moving the film to the left, but I want to somehow scale the clips down to fit in their respected color, and move with it.

Edit: I know I accidently still have a green in the corner, I fixed that but not re-uploading

Answer (score 1):

Leave the color out and make a png out of it.
Then, create a sequenz which has the length of the bar you want.
Insert as many filmframes as you like.
Now simply draw masks around one frame each.

Put the sequenz in your final sequenze where you can animate it.

(Keep in mind that the holes (little squares) normally don't contain images, as they are holes.)

Comment: Masks are not necessary, simply sizing them appropriately on top of the film strip is all that is needed unless the aspect ratio is wrong for the frames.  Otherwise, I agree completely on the approach though.  Certainly place the clips before animating the whole thing as one layer.